# Deleting an event using Event Kit in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ekeventkit, ekevent

I am using Event Kit in my iOS application and creating a event using Event Kit. I am able to create it but I want to give the ability to delete also. But I am not able to do that. I know there is a method for EKEventStore to delete event but I am not able to make event object. I have event identifier as a string but I am not able to create an event object using it. Can someone please guide me to do it?

Regards
Pankaj

Comment: You say you have the event identifier, have you tried to retrieve the event with [`eventWithIdentifier:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009567-CH1-SW19) method on `EKEventStore`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When ever you are creating an event save its id like this:

```
NSString* str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", event.eventIdentifier];
```

pass the id to delete the event, here is code

```
EKEventStore* store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    EKEvent* event2 = [store eventWithIdentifier:str];
    if (event2 != nil) {  
        NSError* error = nil;
        [store removeEvent:event2 span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
    }
```

Comment: I did the same thing on iOS 5/6 but doesn't work. eventWithIdentifier returns null. Identifier is 100% equal. Where is the problem?

Comment: I found `event.eventIdentifier` is always nil, I use `event.calendarItemIdentifier` instead of. And got event by `(EKEvent *)[eventStore calendarItemWithIdentifier:current_calendarItemIdentifier];`

Answer (score 9):

Refer [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) as event.eventIdentifier changes value. So you must keep track of the event.title you set to the event and access the event and delete it

```
NSDate *startDate = <EVENT_START_DATE>;
NSDate *endDate = <EVENT_END_DATE>;

NSPredicate *predicateForEvents = [eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate endDate:endDate calendars:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]]];
//set predicate to search for an event of the calendar(you can set the startdate, enddate and check in the calendars other than the default Calendar)

NSArray *events_Array = [eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate: predicateForEvents];                        
//get array of events from the eventStore

for (EKEvent *eventToCheck in events_Array) 
{
    if( [eventToCheck.title isEqualToString: @"yourEventTitle"] ) 
    {
         NSError *err;
         BOOL success = [eventStore removeEvent:eventToCheck span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
         NSLog( @"event deleted success if value = 1 : %d", success );
         break;

    }
}
```

Comment: That is pretty unreliable. Imagine having 10 events called "Concert" in your calendar.

Comment: Can anyone help for this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33931231/how-to-identify-ekevent-uniquely-with-sync-across-the-devices

Comment: A PERFECT ANSWER!!!! - Just use `startDate` and `endDate` in predicate will solved all your queries. I have edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [EKEvent with eventWithIdentifier on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820501/ekevent-with-eventwithidentifier-on-ios)

I'm also finding that the following code works

```
// eventWithIdentifier returns nil for the external identifier
//EKEvent *eventToRemove = [eventStore eventWithIdentifier:self.expiryCalendarExternalIdentifier];
// So I'm using this method, which seems to work.
- (EKEvent *) getEventForIdentifer: (NSString *) eventIdentifier {
    EKEventStore *eventStore = [Settings getEventStore];
    NSArray *items = [eventStore calendarItemsWithExternalIdentifier:eventIdentifier];
    if ([items count] == 1) {
        return items[0];
    } else {
        [LogFile write:@"getEventForIdentifer: more than one occurrence of event, or no event!"];
        return nil;
    }
}
```

An example of this code in action (untested):

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

EKEvent *newCalendarEvent = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
// Just because we created an EKEvent, the calendarItemExternalIdentifier property of that event has been set.

// I store calendarItemExternalIdentifier (an NSString) in a Core Data
// object, and later fetch it back from core data. 
// Something like:
NSManagedObjectSubclass *coreDataObject = ...
coreDataObject.externalId = newEvent.calendarItemExternalIdentifier;

// So, now let's say we pull the calendarItemExternalIdentifier string from 
// Core Data, and want to remove the event.

NSString *externalId = ... // get calendarItemExternalIdentifier from Core Data

// getEventForIdentifer method from above
EKEvent *eventToRemove = [self getEventForIdentifer:externalId];

NSError *anError = nil;
[eventStore removeEvent:eventToRemove span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&anError];
if (anError) {
   // Something has gone wrong. Report the error.
}
```

Comment: Help. How do I get the event identifier. Very confused

Comment: In my code, I use the calendarItemExternalIdentifier property of the EKEvent object.

Comment: Chris, I still cannot get this to work.  Can you share a code snippet for how you set the calendarItemExternalIdentifier property and then how/where you use it remove an event? Thanks.

Comment: See the example above. Does that help?