# EKEvent with eventWithIdentifier on iOS

Tags: ios, events, calendar, addition, ekevent

If I want to retrieve `EKEvent` from `EKEventStore` with `eventWithIdentifier` method for previously saved event but I always get null.

This is the code for adding event:

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
EKEvent *newEvent = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
newEvent.title = @"Test";
newEvent.availability = EKEventAvailabilityFree;
newEvent.startDate = startDate;
newEvent.endDate = endDate;
[newEvent addAlarm:[EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-15*60]];

newEvent.calendar = [eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents];

NSError *err;
BOOL success = [eventStore saveEvent:newEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];

if (success) {
    if ([newEvent respondsToSelector:@selector(calendarItemIdentifier)]) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:newEvent.calendarItemIdentifier forKey:self.showId];
        NSLog(@"Event ID: %@",newEvent.calendarItemIdentifier);
    }
    else {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:newEvent.UUID forKey:self.showId];
        NSLog(@"Event ID: %@",newEvent.UUID);
    }
}
```

And code for removing event:

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

NSError *err;
BOOL success = YES;

NSLog(@"Event ID: %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:self.showId]);

EKEvent *existingEvent = [eventStore eventWithIdentifier:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:self.showId]];
NSLog(@"Existing event: %@",existingEvent);
if (existingEvent != nil) {
    success = [eventStore removeEvent:existingEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
}
if (success) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:self.showId];
}
```

Why I cannot remove previously added event from calendar with the same event id ?

*This code was tested on iOS 5 (iPad 1) and iOS 6 (new iPad)...*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am using `newEvent.eventIdentifier` instead of `newEvent.calendarItemIdentifier` and so far, using `[store eventWithIdentifier:_project.event_identifier]`, I can retrieve, delete and edit an existing event. you should try.

Comment: That works. I don't actually understand what is calendarItemIdentifier for?

Comment: Well `calendarItemIdentifier` is used when working with `EKCalendarItem` objects but here we're working with `EKEvent` object. - info: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKCalendarItemClassRef/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thats why I thought so. calendarItemIdentifier is also iOS6+ specific. Thanks!

Comment: @Mr_Nizzle, what is _project object that you are referring to?

Comment: @Satyamsvv _project is just an instance of a class Project that i'm using on my app and there's an instance method "event_identifier" where I'm saving the string of the EKEvent identifier for my project

Comment: @Mr_Nizzle EKEvent is a subclass of EKCalendarItem so calendarItemIdentifier should work as well

Comment: Can anyone please help me for this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33931231/how-to-identify-ekevent-uniquely-with-sync-across-the-devices

Answer (score 1):

The documentation warns that "If the calendar of an event changes, its identifier most likely changes as well." Did anything change about the event between the time you stored the eventIdentifer and when you attempted to delete it?

Comment: There is no change on calendar neither on event. I just create event and after after try to delete it with no luck and no error. It's really strange...