# Delete EKEvent from EKEventStore from iOS Calendar App

Tags: ios, iphone

I have added an event on the default calendar on iPhone using the following code:

```
EKEventStore *store=[[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (!granted) {
            return ;
        }
        EKEvent *event=[EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
        event.title=@"This is the event";
        event.startDate=[NSDate date];
        event.endDate =[event.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60];
        event.allDay=YES;
        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
        event.URL=url;
        [event setCalendar:[store defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
        NSError *errr=nil;
        [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&errr]; //        NSLog(@"%@",errr); //        NSLog(@"%@",event.eventIdentifier);

    }];
```

Now I want to delete this event.
The code I tried is this:

```
EKEventStore *store1=[[EKEventStore alloc]init];
            NSPredicate *predicate=[store1 predicateForEventsWithStartDate:[[tableViewScheduleArray objectAtIndex:btn.tag] objectForKey:@"Schedule_Date"] endDate:[[tableViewScheduleArray objectAtIndex:btn.tag] objectForKey:@"Schedule_End_Time"] calendars:nil];
            NSArray *arr=[store eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [store1 removeEvent:[arr objectAtIndex:0] span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:nil];
            });
```

It didn't work, but it didn't result in an error either.

I have tried several pieces of code from Stack Overflow but neither of them worked.

Comment: check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820501/ekevent-with-eventwithidentifier-on-ios
use eventWithIdentifier function also store this and delete this identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution,
It was a silly mistakes by me.

the property "store" which is not declare as strong.
as i changed it worked.

And Above code is working properly.

Comment: If your problem is solved, please accept this as an answer so we can close out this question. Thanks!